# How to write merged geodataframe to shapefile

Tags: python, geopandas, attribute-joins

Tried the following code. I am able to see the merged data in the console but I don't get any output file. Running my code does not raise any errors either.

```py
import geopandas
import pathlib
import fiona
import os
import pandas

filename1 = '/Users/alexander/Code/Python/11_gis/GeoPandas/DF1.geojson'
file1 = open(filename1)
gdf1 = geopandas.read_file(file1)


filename2 = '/Users/alexander/Code/Python/11_gis/GeoPandas/DF2.csv'
file2 = open(filename2)
gdf2 = geopandas.read_file(file2)

gdf1 = gdf1.merge(gdf2,on='OMCODE')


gdf1.to_file("output.shp", driver='ESRI shapefile')
```

**Sample of GeoJSON :**

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "DF1",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "XXX-AAN-NCB", "Local_code": "3502", "OMCODE": "ANNIC", "Name": "Nicobars", "areaKM": 1713.91369, "areaMiles": 661.74313 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 93.668786592478256, 7.025389295324629 ], [ 93.671142592480436, 7.031861795330656 ], [ 93.660415592470457,
```

**Sample of CSV to be joined by common field OMCODE**

```
OMCODE  Mon Abdul   Abnaki  Abor
ABATH               2
ABBAN               
ABBEL   1       34  
ABBIG               
ABBLA               
ABBON           1   
ABBRZ       4       
ABCAL               
ABCLE               
ABCLH               
ABCYC               4
ABDV3       4
```

Comment: @user2856 I have added the samples, not sure how format the code

Comment: Same way you formatted your python code.  Either wrap it in ``` or use the `{}` button. I've done it for you.

Comment: Your geojson is invalid/incomplete.

Comment: OK, thanks !  I will look at the geojson again

Comment: I'm not saying your actual geojson is invalid/incomplete, just the sample. Looks like you've copy/pasted only part of a `Feature` as the `geometry` array doesn't have a closing `y` coordinate or `]` bracket, nor is there closing bracket/brace for the `features` array and `FeatureCollection` object.

Comment: I would add some output steps after your .read_file() lines, to examine each gdf. For example `print ( gdf1 )`. This should give you insight into whether your files are loading the way you expect.

Comment: The open() function calls appear redundant?  I would just pass the filename as a string into read_file().

Comment: geopandas.read_file expects a geometry column. That is not present in your CSV file. Instead I would use `pandas.read_csv`

Comment: @MikeHoney that was the issue thanks !  This is file with a very large number of columns  so this saved me a lot of work :)

Comment: Great - glad to hear it. I've reposted my comments as an answer - jonesing for that dopamine hit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add some output steps after your .read_file() lines, to examine each gdf. For example print ( gdf1 ). This should give you insight into whether your files are loading the way you expect.

The open() function calls appear redundant? I would just pass the filename as a string into read_file().

geopandas.read_file expects a geometry column. That is not present in your CSV file. Instead I would use pandas.read_csv